# python thread lock doesn't lock the rest of thread

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

here is my code:

```
def inner_func(lock):
    with lock:
        print (f'{threading.current_thread().getName()} - inner_function - lock - acquire')
        print (f'{threading.current_thread().getName()} - inner_function - lock - processing')
        print (f'{threading.current_thread().getName()} - inner_function - lock - release')
    print(f'{threading.current_thread().getName()} - inner_function')

def outer_func(a, lock):
    inner_func(lock)
    print(f'{threading.current_thread().getName()} - outsider_function - input: {a}')

class Worker():
    def __init__(self, num_threads, input_item):
        self.t             = threading
        self.lock          = self.t.Lock()
        self.q             = queue.Queue()
        self.num_thread    = num_threads
        self.input_item    = input_item

    def worker(self):
        while True:
            item = self.q.get()
            if item:    item.append(self.lock)
            if not item:
                break
            outer_func(*item)
            self.q.task_done()

    def main(self):
        threads = []
        for _ in range(self.num_thread):
            t = self.t.Thread(target=self.worker)
            t.start()
            threads.append(t)

        for item in self.input_item:
            self.q.put(item)
        self.q.join()
        for _ in range(self.num_thread):
            self.q.put(None)
        for t in threads:
            t.join()

container = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f'], ['g']]
Worker(7, container).main()
```

I am trying to create `inner_func` which is used by `outer_func` to testify if `threading.Lock()` can pass to sub-function. 
After the run, it doesn't seem to me that the lock locks other threads, as the print message shows up other messages between my lock's message.

The print result as the following:

```
.......(other print)
Thread-6 - inner_function - lock - acquire
Thread-7 - outsider_function - input: c
Thread-6 - inner_function - lock - processing
Thread-6 - inner_function - lock - release
.......(other print)
```

As above indicated, Thread-6 already acquire the lock, but Thread-7 still active before the release of lock in Thread-6.

Does it mean the lock doesn't work? if not, how can I prove when the lock is active? or when other thread is not active during active of lock in single thread.

The following is another problem on print:

```
Thread-6 - outsider_function - input: dThread-1 - inner_function - lock - acquire
```

above should print in two different lines. how to fix it? thanks.

Comment: Seems to work as expected for me. Please post your output and what you expected the output to be.

Comment: I think I didn't ask my question clearly. already edit my question with output. thanks.

Comment: @Kai ***`Thread-7 - outsider_function - input: c`***: Nothing wrong with this, this prints after the `lock` has been released and is outside of **any** `lock`. Even the next `Thread-6 - inner_function - lock - acquire` **has aquired** before. The overlapping `print` could be happen as `print` is not **atomic**.

Comment: @stovfl , if the print is atomic, or it is not printing in perfect sequence. How could I debug in aspect of checking lock status? My understanding is, during ‘with lock:’ the program only allow print out ‘acquire’, ‘process’, and ‘release’ in thread-6, and not allow to process anything in other threads or outside ‘with lock’. By having ‘thread-7.....input : c’ between thread-6, it seem to me the lock is not working. Is there any other way to check lock status, other than by reading print messages?

Comment: @Kai ***"How could I debug in aspect of checking lock status?"***: Remove **ALL** your `print` statements, it's to much that leads to confusing. Use **only one** `print('locked, timestamp:{}'.format(time.time()))` right after `with lock:`. Also add `time.sleep(1)` to simulate a **long runninig task**. On success, the timestamps should be in order.

Comment: Thank, it works. And just figure out why sometime thread-7's message appears between thread-6 (in lock status). It is because thread-7 may occur at the same start-time or end-time of thread-6(in lock status).

Comment: When you use `with lock`, then any code within those blocks will be prevented from running concurrently with any other code that is also within such a block. But that has no effect on code that is not within a `with lock` block. So, any of your `print` statements that are not within such a block may occur at any time regardless of what is going on elsewhere with the `lock`.

Comment: @John, thanks, that is even more clear to my confusion. I through while “with lock” any thing other than current thread would temporary stop processing. Which is not true. I think I get more clear on logic of threading.Lock(). Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

The prints outside the `with lock:` block are unordered with respect to the lock. If you want them ordered you need to wrap them in their own `with lock:`.

Consider what:

```
def inner_func(lock):
    with lock:
        print (f'{threading.current_thread().getName()} - inner_function - lock - acquire')
        print (f'{threading.current_thread().getName()} - inner_function - lock - processing')
        print (f'{threading.current_thread().getName()} - inner_function - lock - release')
    with lock:    
        print(f'{threading.current_thread().getName()} - inner_function')

def outer_func(a, lock):
    inner_func(lock)
    with lock:    
        print(f'{threading.current_thread().getName()} - outsider_function - input: {a}')
```

does.

Comment: thank for your advice. however, I would not mind the print without 'with lock' processes the same time as other threads' print. I only want the print proof the lock is working. for example, when print, it expect should be: acquire > process, 
 > release,  and it should not be: acquire > (print from other thread) > (print from other thread) > process > release.